# Is there a way to force active directory group assignation without logoff/login?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

as stated [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/725841/is-there-a-way-to-force-group-membership-changes-to-be-refreshed-on-clients) and [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/932623/what-is-the-minimum-action-required-in-order-to-have-access-to-a-newly-authorize), it looks like there is no way to avoid a user logoff/login in order to activate a new group assignation for this user (my use case was : activate an access to a shared folder by adding a user in a group).

Is there still no way to force the user group mapping assignation (without ending the session) with latest versions of Windows/Active directory ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can try `klist purge` then use `runas` the same logged in user to recreate the kerberos session

Comment: Lock and unlock does the same thing. You need the session refresh and there's no deterministic way to do it outside of a logon process, which the lock/unlock will do. Edit: though it's an async process, so it takes a beat for the tickets to arrive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the minimum action required in order to have access to a newly authorized server folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/932623/what-is-the-minimum-action-required-in-order-to-have-access-to-a-newly-authorize)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your question has already been answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/932623/what-is-the-minimum-action-required-in-order-to-have-access-to-a-newly-authorize?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The accepted answer on this question basically tells you all you need.